# Object Type Error calling C# from VBA

Tags: c#, vba, vsto

I have a an Excel addin written in C# I am trying to call from VBA in Excel. In VBA I generate several arrays to pass:

```
Dim Identifiers() As Variant
Dim Variables() As Variant
Dim Times() As Variant
...
Dim QaddIn As COMAddIn
Dim QTool As Object
Dim results As Variant
Set QaddIn = Application.COMAddIns("QTool")
QaddIn.Connect = True
Set QTool = QaddIn.Object

results = QTool.GetQData(datasetName, Identifiers, Variables, Times, timeString)
```

`GetQData` is defined in C# as:

```
string[] GetQData(string DatasetName, object[] Identifiers, object[] Variables, object[] TimeCodes,
                                string TimeString);
```

But when I run the code, VBA throws the error `object of type 'system.object[*]' cannot be converted to object of type 'system.object[]'`. This same code worked fine passing variant arrays defined with a static length, as in `Dim Identifiers(3) As Variant`. What is the difference between what I am trying to pass now?

Comment: Can you please provide more code for example the GETCIQData Method also keep in mind that C# does not use Variants..

Comment: since you are trying to call it that way ..are you missing some Invoke Call or method..?

Comment: C# does not use variants - it reads the passed arrays as Object arrays. Like I said, it works fine with a fixed-length array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the array I was attempting to pass to C# was indexed from 1, that is, it was an `Array(1 to 5)` rather than an `Array(0 to 4)`. It's unfortunate that passing an array indexed from 1 fails, because `Range.Value` and all of the `WorksheetFunction` methods return arrays indexed from 1.

I wrote the following code in VBA to reindex my arrays from zero before passing them:

```
Function ShiftArray(ThisArray() As Variant) As Variant    
    Dim lb As Long, ub As Long
    Dim NewArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    lb = LBound(ThisArray)
    ub = UBound(ThisArray)

    ReDim NewArray(0 To (ub - lb))

    For i = 0 To (ub - lb)
        NewArray(i) = ThisArray(i + lb)
    Next i

    ShiftArray = NewArray    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that variable length arrays and fixed length arrays are not the same.  vba in general will be pretty forgiving so you generally get away with it, but C# isn't.  It can't be sure that you mean to convert the array to a fixed length array.  You should look for a method on the Identifiers object to convert it to a fixed length array.  This will probably then look something like:

```
results = CIQTool.GetCIQData(datasetName, Identifiers.ToArray(), Variables.ToArray(), Times.ToArray(), timeString)
```

I'm not sure the exact naming of that method though so use the code completion to look for it.

Comment: I was unable to find a method like that - though that could be because of VBA's poor documentation. But I figured out my problem, as described in my answer. Thanks for your help.